# Vue.js and vuex this.$store return undefined after adding it to new Vue({store})

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuex

I have gone through the available solutions on here, but none seems to work for my situation.

1. [Vue.js and vuex: this.$store is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47814626/vue-js-and-vuex-this-store-is-undefined)
2. [Vuex store this.$store is undefined in Vue.js component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50848355/vuex-store-this-store-is-undefined-in-vue-js-component)
3. https://pinoria.com/how-to-fix-this-store-is-undefined-with-vue-js-and-vuex/

Successfully imported the store object into my main.js. Checked by logging it.

Added store to my vue instance, but I cannot access it through this.$store in my components.

```
Error - Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "TypeError: Cannot read 
properties of undefined (reading 'error')"

console.log(this.$store) in my components returns undefined.
```

codesandbox link -  https://codesandbox.io/s/vdr5js

store.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  state: {
    token: null,
    user: null,
    isUserLoggedin: false
  },
  mutations: {
    setToken (state, token) {
      state.token = token
      if (token) {
        state.isUserLoggedIn = true
      } else {
        state.isUserLoggedIn = false
      }
    },
    setUser (state, user) {
      state.user = user
    }
  },
  actions: {
    setToken ({commit}, token) {
      commit('setToken', token)
    },
    setUser ({commit}, user) {
      commit('setUser', user)
    }
  }
})
```

main.js

```
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an 
alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import store from '@/store/store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

console.log(store) // returns store object

Vue.use(Vuetify)

sync(store, router)

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

Login component

```
<script>
import AuthenticationService from '@/services/AuthenticationService'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      error: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async login () {
      try {
        const response = await AuthenticationService.login({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        })
        this.$store.dispatch('setToken', response.data.token) //throw error
        this.$store.dispatch('setUser', response.data.user)
      } catch (error) {
        this.error = error.responsedata.error
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I can access this.$router and this.$store in the Header.vue component
Please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Its looks like your `vue-router-sync` is not configured properly. Look at this answer to make sure your configuration is right- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44171210/what-is-vuex-router-sync-for#:~:text=vuex%2Drouter%2Dsync%20is%20a,%24router%20.

Comment: Please can you clarify how this makes this.$store return undefined?

Comment: I suggest you create a *runnable* [mcve] by [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) your project into codesandbox. What you posted is not runnable which significantly reduces your chances of getting a useful answer. From what you posted, I'd say `error.responseData` is not defined, hence you can't access its `error`. Replace `this.error = error.responsedata.error` with `console.log(error)` and have a look at the error structure.

Comment: Thanks, here is the codesandbox link - https://codesandbox.io/s/vdr5js

Comment: codesandbox can't run both frontend and backend. It's only for frontend.